# kafkacat's -o (offset to start consuming from) option

Tags: apache-kafka, kcat

Will execute the following kafkacat command with the -o (offset to start consuming from) option but without the -G (group id) option affect other consumer groups?

```
kafkacat -C -b 10.52.1.1:9092,10.52.1.2:9092,10.52.1.3:9092 -t MyTopic -o beginning
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, kafkacat in standalone consumer mode (`-C`) will not join or affect any consumer group, it is safe to use without interfering with existing consumer groups.